# Sprache: How to exclude letters from numeric matches?

Tags: c#, .net, sprache

Using the monadic parser [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache), looking to match numeric characters (0..9), excluding non-numeric characters, but leading or trailing whitespace is ok.

I thought this should work:

```
public static readonly Parser<string>
    Number = Parse.Numeric.Except(Parse.Letter).AtLeastOnce().Text().Token();
```

or this:

```
public static readonly Parser<int>
    Number = Parse.Number.Select(int.Parse).Token();
```

Both work for all cases I could think of, except trailing text:

```
[Test]
public void Number_ParseNumberWithTrailingLetter_WasUnsuccessfull()
{
    var input = new Input("123bogus");
    IResult<string> result = Lexicon.Number(input);
    Assert.IsFalse(result.WasSuccessful);
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you `123a456` to return `123456`?  Or `123`?

Comment: Neither, it shouldn't parse. I'm after only numbers between whitespace. Updated question with a simpler expression which exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Is number/whitespace/number ok?  I.e. should `"123 456"` parse as two discrete numbers?  Or fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to accept a single number only, then to eliminate the trailing text use a `.End()` clause, which asserts that the end of the string is reached:

```
public static readonly Parser<int> MatchInt =
      Parse.Number.Select(int.Parse).Token().End();
```

If instead you want to accept subsequent numbers in the input stream (separated by spaces), you could use a `.Then()` clause to give you all of them.  Something like:

```
public static readonly Parser<int> MatchInt = Parse.Number.Select(int.Parse).Token();
public static readonly Parser<IEnumerable<int>> MatchIntList = 
      from int1 in MatchInt
      from intRest in Parse.WhiteSpace.AtLeastOnce().Then(_ => MatchInt).Many().End()
      select new List<int>() { int1 }.Concat(intRest);
```

Not tested - but hopefully enough to go in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Geoff! Only want a single number parsed, so the former solution works as expected.